# The tf.train.batch shape mismatch with self defined np.array data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the slim library to train my own resnet_v2_152 and

constructing my own image numpy array data which is stacked with 20 images.

It means that my numpy array size will be

```
[224, 224, 20]
```

I have not problem when converting the data into tfrecords by using bytes conversion and get the image array data after preprocessed but it always shows the error of

```
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: 
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, 
Shape mismatch in tuple component 0. Expected [224,224,3], got [224,224,20]
```

and

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_5_batch/fifo_queue' 
is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
```

when I apply the tf.train.batch

Below is the part of my code,

```
    dataset = dataset_factory.get_dataset(
        FLAGS.datasetname, FLAGS.dataset, FLAGS.dataset_dir)

    network_fn = nets_factory.get_network_fn(
        FLAGS.model_name,
        num_classes=101,
        is_training=True)

    provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(
          dataset,
          num_readers=4,
          common_queue_capacity=20 * FLAGS.batch_size,
          common_queue_min=10 * FLAGS.batch_size)
    [image, label] = provider.get(['image', 'label'])
    label -= 0

    preprocessing_name = FLAGS.preprocessing_name or FLAGS.model_name
    image_preprocessing_fn = preprocessing_factory.get_preprocessing(preprocessing_name, is_training=True)

    eval_image_size = FLAGS.eval_image_size or network_fn.default_image_size
    image = image_preprocessing_fn(image, eval_image_size, eval_image_size)

    #Batch size is 1
    images, labels = tf.train.batch(
          [image, label],
          batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
          num_threads=4,
          capacity=5 * FLAGS.batch_size)   

    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
            tf.local_variables_initializer())

    #This part to see the fetched results
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        sess.run(init_op)
        im = sess.run(images)
        l = sess.run(label)
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

I'm insisting to follow the style in train_image_classifier.py is because I would like to use the default training pattern provided by the slim library.

I will really appreciate your help and answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced by myself and find out the error is due to the dimension proprocessed image size in

by changing the code in

```
vgg_preprocessing.py

image.set_shape([output_height, output_width, 3])
```

into

```
image.set_shape([output_height, output_width, channels])
```

However, I would like to know is there any effect by changing this, if someone can answer me then i would really appreciate. Thanks